# How to repeat array elements to form an nxm dimensional array or matrix

Tags: tensorflow

I have an array; y = [ 1.   0.5   0.33333333    0.25   0.2    0.16666667   0.14285714   0.125    0.11111111    0.1 ] and 1 want to repeat the same elements to form a (10, 10) square matrix in tensorflow. I wrote the following code;

```
y1 = tf.tile(y, [10], axis = 1)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(y))
```

Please help me as I'm a complete beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y = [ 1., 0.5, 0.33333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666667, 0.14285714, 0.125, 0.11111111, 0.1 ] 
y = np.array(y).reshape((1, 10))
y1 = tf.tile(y, [10, 1])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(y1.shape)
    print(sess.run(y1))
```

Output:

```
(10, 10)
[[ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]
 [ 1.          0.5         0.33333333  0.25        0.2         0.16666667
   0.14285714  0.125       0.11111111  0.1       ]]
```